# Flutter : Restrict price localization to english only

Tags: flutter, localization

My app supports two localizations 1] English 2] Arabic. Localization is working perfectly throughout the app.

But there are certain scenarios where I need to show text only in the English language but app changing it to as per selected localization. So all prices are shown in Arabic for Arabic localization.

I tried to put explicit Locale (NOT sure whether it is supposed to do like this) in a Text widget but still, that didn't work for me.

```
Text('3434', // Dynamic String from server
      locale: Locale('en'),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))
```

Actual Result When Arabic Localization is selected :

[image]

Expected Result :

[image]

Comment: maybe better create another string in Arabic and put English translation here?

Comment: Actually, these strings I can not keep in localized string file as this is dynamic data coming from a server. Just for the sample, I have added '3434' in the above code.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand, but what the actual result and what the result you what to receive?(in a case for '3434')

Comment: Just updated the question with actual & expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set font-family specifically to those texts that doesn't need the arabic font. That way, it will override the default one.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set fontFamily to Text Widget to whichever language-specific you want. For me, I just set the fontFamily like this,

```
Text(
    value,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
  ),
```

Hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

`Text(item.price, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,)`  will make the TextDirection to be always in English 'ltr' left to right.

I hope that helps.